# Parsing HEVC (H265) pseudocode in reference guide

Tags: parsing, hevc

Looking the H265 reference at

https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-H.265-201802-S!!PDF-E&type=items

go to function `st_ref_pic_set( stRpsIdx )` at 7.3.7

inside that function there is a `for` loop with `j` variable.

```
for (j=0; j<=NumDeltaPocs[ refRpsIdc], j++){

}
```

where `NumDeltaPocs` is derived as:

```
NumDeltaPocs[ stRpsIdx ] = NumNegativePics[ stRpsIdx ] 
                         + NumPositivePics[ stRpsIdx ]
```

as you can see, it seems that `num_negative_pics` and `num_positive_pics` are unknown values. They are parsed in the `else` branch in pseudocode at 7.3.7

How can I implement that pseudocode?

Comment: I can see definitions for `num_negative_pics` and `num_positive_pics` on page #104 (pdf page 122).

Comment: I'm not able to retrieve the value of num_negative_pics and num_positive_pics from that definition.

Comment: `NumNegativePics` and `num_negative_pics` are not the same. And if your worry is (7-63) `NumNegativePics[ stRpsIdx ] = num_negative_pics`, that is only one case of setting `NumNegativePics`, while (7-61) actually calculates it.